# WFS Layer doesnt work on QGIS

Tags: wfs, qgis-3

So i have been trying to connect the following WFS resource to QGIS 3.4.4.

https://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Cadastre_WFS/MapServer

It connects without problems, lets me add the layer to the map without complaint but the layer is actually empty. 
When I try to open the attribute table it says "Loading features for layer XY 0%" and never progresses.
This relates to the standard AddLayer/WFS tool. I have also tried to add it via the AddLayer/ArcGIS Feature Server tool. since the resource seems to lie on a ArcGIS Server, but it replied with en error message "Failed to retrieve service capabilities: Network error: Error transferring http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/services/public/NSW_Cadastre_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer?f=json - server replied: Bad Request"

The resource loads without problems in ArcGIS

Comment: update: i was able to open the attribute table, everything seems fine here: a few thousand features, each columns field filled with values, etc

Comment: You don't seem to be attempting to connect to the WFS service of that ArcGIS Server. Instead, try http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/services/public/NSW_Cadastre_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS

Comment: i dont seem to be able to use your link: when i use it QGIS automatically changes it back to the one i posted, both in the standart addWFS tool and in the addArcGISWFS tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a WFS server, they named their service badly.

What you link to is a ArcGIS MapServer, something like a WMS. I can load its raster layers using `Layer` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add ArcGIS MapServer Layer`.

They do also provide it as WFS though, there is a tiny link at the top of the site which works (apart from being painfully slow) if I add it via `Layer` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add WFS Layer`: http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/services/public/NSW_Cadastre_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS

Comment: it doesnt work for me, still same behaviour as outlined in the initial post, tried it on two different PC´s. QGIS changes the link to http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/services/public/NSW_Cadastre_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer ,so it deletes the last part of your link. is supposed to do that?

Comment: Yes, that is ok.